# problems controlling a background-image with javascript during a mouse over effect within a thumbnail div

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this is a fairly common question, but I assure you I've spent the last two days reading through to see if I can figure it out on my own, but alas I'm here at your feet hoping for some a advice. I'm still in the beginning stages of learning javascript.

Basically, I have a series of thumbnails contained by a div class that has a repeating background image giving it a subtle texture. I also have some java script that successfully highlights the individual div container blue while the mouse hovers over the thumbnail image. The problem I'm having is that the solid blue effect doesn't mesh too well with the existing background image I've chosen for the thumbnail div. I've been trying to toggle the  background image on/off while the blue hover effect is taking place, but I've only been able to turn it off permanently after a single mouse over/hover.

Here's the javascript:

```
    // this controls the entire div tag and turns it blue
$('.pGrid div a').hover(
    function(){
        //this if-statement should toggle whether or not the striped background shows when the mouse is hovering
        if ($('.pGrid div a').hover !=0) {
        $('.pGrid div a').parent().css({ backgroundImage: "none" });
        }
        else {
         $('.pGrid div a').parent().style({ backgroundImage: "url('../images/background_stripes_white.gif')" });    
            }
        //mouse over turn div blue
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: "#006699",
            color: "#ffffff"
            }, 350);    
            // this controls the word-highlight part
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: "#006699",
            color: "#ffffff"
            }, 350);
        },
        // mouse out
    function(){
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: "#d0d0d0",
            color: "#000000"
            }, 350);
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: "#d0d0d0",
            color: "#006699"
            }, 350);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the background image, just swap CSS class names. Have one with the image and one without.

You should also probably be using `display:block` on your A-tag and applying the background to it directly (via a CSS class) instead of the parent item.

Comment: Do I need to make a new function with toggleClass? or can I still use a  if-else statement to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use toggleClass, or addClass/RemoveClass whatever fits your code pattern the best.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. I had to nix the if-else statements and place a single line of code in each function stating to either set background to none or to switch back to the original. Also, it turns out I was referencing the file extensions all wrong and had to remove the '../' part. Thank you for the help @Diodeus much appreciated!